# R:How to replace string to integer?

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataset looks like:

```
classification  Interest    Age     Gender
Card battle     IL029       18-24   male
Card battle     IL001       45-54   male
Card battle     IL001       18-24   male
Card battle     IL001       35-44   male
Card battle     IL001       35-44   male
Card battle     IL013       35-44   male
```

How to replace "18-24" to 20,"35-44" to 40 and "45-54" to 50 in the age column?

Comment: Have you thought about what you would like to replace them with?

Comment: Not sure if you what's the desired output, but you could do `factor(df$Age, labels = c("20", "40", "50"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this

```
data$age <- as.character(data$age)
data$age[which(data$age=="18-24")] <- "20"
data$age[which(data$age=="35-44")] <- "40"
data$age[which(data$age=="45-54")] <- "50"
data$age <- as.numeric(data$age)
```

Answer (score 4):

This will replace `Age` with a factor having labels 20, 40 and 50:

```
transform(DF, Age = factor(Age, 
       levels = c("18-24", "35-44", "45-54"),
       labels = c(20, 40, 50)))
```

giving:

```
  classification Interest Age Gender
1    Card battle    IL029  20   male
2    Card battle    IL001  50   male
3    Card battle    IL001  20   male
4    Card battle    IL001  40   male
5    Card battle    IL001  40   male
6    Card battle    IL013  40   male
```

Actually it can likely be reduced to this although the above is a bit safer:

```
transform(DF, Age = factor(Age, labels = c(20, 40, 50)))
```

If you prefer an integer column then:

```
transform(DF, Age = as.integer(as.character(
       factor(Age, 
         levels = c("18-24", "35-44", "45-54"),
         labels = c(20, 40, 50)
       )
 )))
```

and, again, we could likely omit the `levels` argument:

```
transform(DF, Age = as.integer(as.character(factor(Age, labels = c(20, 40, 50)))))
```

**Note:** We used this as input:

```
DF <-
structure(list(classification = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "Card battle", class = "factor"), Interest = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("IL001", "IL013", "IL029"), class = "factor"), 
    Age = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("18-24", 
    "35-44", "45-54"), class = "factor"), Gender = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "male", class = "factor")), .Names = c("classification", 
"Interest", "Age", "Gender"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Didn't notice that but at any rate note that your comment might not work depending on the mapping of factor levels to labels  whereas the answer here should work.

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` solution is to merge (much easier to extend to more complicated cases):

```
library(data.table)
#your data
DT = data.table(
  classification = "Card battle",
  Interest = sprintf('IL%03d', c(29, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13)),
  Age = c("18-24","45-54","18-24", rep("35-44", 3L)),
  Gender = "male"
)

#conversion table
convert = data.table(
  Age_range = c("18-24", "45-54", "35-44"),
  #need to keep as string here since 
  #  the target column to overwrite is character
  Age_middle = paste0(c(20, 40, 50))
)

#replace Age, then set its class
DT[convert, on = c(Age = 'Age_range'), Age := i.Age_middle]
#  now convert back to numeric
DT[ , Age := as.numeric(Age)]
```

You might consider keeping the range column around, and simply adding a rounded age column, which would make for cleaner code:

```
convert = data.table(
  Age_range = c("18-24","45-54","35-44"),
  Age_middle = c(20L,40L,50L)
)

DT[convert, Age_middle := i.Age_middle]
DT
#    classification Interest   Age Gender age_rounded
# 1:    Card battle    IL029 18-24   male          20
# 2:    Card battle    IL001 18-24   male          20
# 3:    Card battle    IL001 35-44   male          50
# 4:    Card battle    IL001 35-44   male          50
# 5:    Card battle    IL013 35-44   male          50
# 6:    Card battle    IL001 45-54   male          40
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using `regex`, capturing the second to last digit and putting a 0 after:

```
DF$Age <- as.numeric(sub(".*(\\d)\\d$", "\\10", as.character(DF$Age)))
```

(or simply `as.numeric(sub(".*(\\d)\\d$", "\\10", DF$Age))` if `Age` is not a factor)

```
DF
#  classification Interest Age Gender
#1    Card battle    IL029  20   male
#2    Card battle    IL001  50   male
#3    Card battle    IL001  20   male
#4    Card battle    IL001  40   male
#5    Card battle    IL001  40   male
#6    Card battle    IL013  40   male
```